# Spinner with Custom Text view cuts in Lollipop devices

Tags: android, textview, spinner, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a spinner with custom text view:

Below is the code :

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:prompt="@string/list" />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#3D98E1"
```

On Android 5.0+ (Lollipop devices) the text cuts into half and displayed.

i need the spinner height to be 30dp only, how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cant understand your requirements, but if you want complete control on spinner just use this technique.

You can create a custom spinner using ListPopupWindow to a TextView means when a TextView is clicked a ListPopupWindow open like spinner dropdown list and you can choose a element. If you need I will help you in that.

```
ListPopupWindow numberList;
TextView spDays;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() listTrans;

in oncreate() spDays.setonclicklistner(this);spDays.setText("Select");
setNumberListSpinnerView();

in onclick(){
when spDays clicked :- numberList.show();
}


void setNumberListSpinnerView() {

numberList= new ListPopupWindow(this);
numberList.setAnchorView(spDays);

numberList.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    getListItem();
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Map map = listTrans.get(position);
        spDays.setText(map.get("circle_name").toString());
        circle_name = map.get("circle_name") + "";
        circle_id = map.get("circle_id").toString();
        circleList.dismiss();
        Log.d("Circle id:", circle_id + "");
        getRetails();

    }
}));
}


void getListItem(){
String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
listTrans = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> tran = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String number : numbers) {
    tran.put("numbers", number);
    listTrans.add(tran);
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AddRetailSurvey.this, listTrans,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        new String[]{"numbers"},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
numberList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Check this code and modify it with your requirement. If you found any problem I am here to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when i added dummy padding of 1dp the text wasn't cut anymore.

```
<style name="YourSpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:gravity">center|start</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```